# Specific intervals ggplot x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the x axis to start at `[-1...-49]` in that order, not including 0 to 30, then reverse order `[50, 40, 30]`.

having problem using `xlim` and not including `0:30`,

have tried using `x_scale_continuous`

[image: Plot Can be found here for further clarification]

Answer (score 0):

You could disassociate your labels from their numeric values by converting the variable to a factor. Factors can have arbitrarily ordered levels (which would then just happen to be called "10" "30" "20" etc.)